# To make the second div slide from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am working on hide and show functionality.
I have one bug in my code;
when I click the first  div, the content is opening from down to top,
whereas when I click the second div it opens from right to left. It should open from top to bottom.
How to fix it?

Providing my code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/45/

```
 <div id='firstRadio'>
        <div class="first" > First </div>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#firstRadio").click(function() {
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#secondRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv").hide("slow");
        $("#secondHiddenDiv").show("slow");
    });
    $("#thirdRadio").click(function() {
        $("#firstHiddenDiv, #secondHiddenDiv").hide("slow"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: i think it is due to messed up CSS.

Comment: @Pawal: can you update in the fiddle...

Comment: Jquery is revealing it from the right because of the `float: right`.

Comment: looks like this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2syzQ/46/ , note that you seem to want position the hidden divs absolutely but you did not specify any `position:absolute`.

Comment: @will: can u update in the fiddle...

Comment: @user3662272 just trying removing the `float: right` in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve made some changes to your HTML structure.

You can see the update here: http://jsfiddle.net/2syzQ/51/

HTML:

```
<div class="first" id='firstRadio'> 
    First 
    <div id='firstHiddenDiv'>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
       Text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second" id='secondRadio'> 
    Second 
    <div id='secondHiddenDiv'>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
#container > div { position: relative; } 
.first > div, .second > div { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0; }
```